# Imprimir 2 variables en una sola linea en shell script

Tags: shell-script

Estoy realizando un pequeño programa en shell script pero el problema es que no puedo imprimir 2 variables en una sola linea con un buen formato.

Ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
top=70
espacio_fs=`df -h | tr -s " " "," | cut -d"," -f6  | sed '1d'`
espacio=`df -h | tr -s " " "," | cut -d"," -f5 | tr -s "%" " " | tail -n +2`
for i in $espacio
do
    if [ "$i" -le "$top" ] ; then
 echo "$espacio_fs" "$espacio"  > fss.txt
else
echo "No existen filesystems mayores al 70%"
```

El resultado que me arroja en la salida fss.txt es:

```
Filesystem mayores a 70% son:

/
/dump
/tmp
/backup
/oracle
/grid
/boot
/dev/shm 
4
8
3
22
85
57
6
31
```

Nesesito imprimir esa salida con el siguiente formato

```
Filesystem mayores a 70% son:

Filesytem              Uso(%)
/                      4
/dump                  8
/tmp                   3
/backup                22
/oracle                85 
/grid                  57
/boot                  6
/dev/shm               31
```

Como puede lograr esa concatenación?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, no hace falta nada de todo esto. Solo necesitas imprimir las columnas 1 y 5 de la salida d `df`, entonces haz:

```
$ df -h  | awk '{print  $1, $5}'
Filesystem Use%
dev 0%
run 1%
/dev/sda5 91%
tmpfs 4%
tmpfs 0%
tmpfs 1%
/dev/sda6 71%
tmpfs 1%
```

Y para solo guardar lineas que tengan mas que 70% de uso, primero quita el `%` para quedar solo con la cifra y después:

```
$ df -h  | awk '{gsub(/%/,""); if($5>=70){print  $1, $5}}'
Filesystem Use
/dev/sda5 91
/dev/sda6 71
```

Y, para formatearlo mejor, usa `printf`:

```
$ df -h  | awk '{gsub(/%/,""); if($5>=70){printf "%-30s %3s\n",  $1, $5}}'
Filesystem                     Use
/dev/sda5                       91
/dev/sda6                       71
```

---

Si quieres usar tu script, el problema es que tus variables son así:

```
$ echo "$espacio_fs"
/dev 
/run 
/ 
/dev/shm 
/sys/fs/cgroup 
/tmp 
/home 
/run/user/1000 
$ echo "$espacio"
0 
1 
91 
4 
0 
1 
71 
1
```

Es decir, tus dos variables tienen todos los datos separados con `\n`, pero no se ve si lo imprimes sin comillas (`echo $var` en vez de lo correcto `echo "$var"`). Entonces tu programa funciona perfectamente, pero no es la manera de hacer lo que quieres. Podrías hacer algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash
top=170
mapfile -t espacio_fs < <(df -h | tr -s " " "," | cut -d"," -f6  | sed '1d')
mapfile -t espacio < <(df -h | tr -s " " "," | cut -d"," -f5 | tr -s "%" " " | tail -n +2)

encontrados=0
for ((i=0; i<${#espacio[@]}; i++)); do
  if [ "${espacio[i]}" -ge "$top" ] ; then
    if [[ $encontrados == 0 ]]; then
        printf '%-30s %4s\n' "Filesystem" "Uso(%)" > fss.txt
    fi
    ## Aquí quieres >> y no > ya que con >, cada nueva linea
    ## borraria el contenido del fss.txt
    printf '%-30s %4s\n' "${espacio_fs[i]}" "${espacio[i]}" >> fss.txt
    ((encontrados++))
  fi
done
if [[ $encontrados == 0 ]]; then
  echo "No existen filesystems mayores al 70%"
fi
```